# Dumping physical memory

Tags: windows, windows-xp, crash, bsod

How do I troubleshoot a machine that is displaying a message that it is beginning to dump physical memory?

Comment: Can you provide us the error?

Answer (score 2):

This blue screen indicates that some code running in the kernel has performed some invalid operation. This very often is caused by poorly-written device drivers.

When you see this screen (usually called the blue screen of death), it indicates which type of problem occurred. Some possible examples of the stop message are IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL or PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.  Each type of stop message indicates a different type of failure, but general troubleshooting steps for these problems are:

- If you added any hardware recently, remove it and see if the problem goes away.
- If the problem goes away with a particular piece of hardware removed, then update the driver for that hardware.
- Update any other drivers such as video card, sound card, or hard disk controller.
- As a last resort, reinstall the operating system.